# Finding a recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I am trying to figure out a recurrence for these numbers:

$f(1)=0$

$f(4)=16$

$f(16)=128$

$f(64)=768$

The base case is $f(1)=0$ the numbers inputed into f must be powers of 4. I am not sure what the recursive formula should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence is $f(n)=4n+4*f(n/4)$ with a base case of $f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

try this expression : $f(2^{n})=2n2^{n}$

Comment: I am trying to find a formula that is a recurrence of itself. ie $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$